# Data binding when data model depends on another data model's properties

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a `Node` class (represented by rectangles on-screen) as well as a `Link` class (represented by arrows between the rectangles).

In terms of data, nodes and links have their own data properties. But a `Link`'s coordinates are equal to its two constituting nodes coordinates; i.e.

- link.x1 = node1.x
- link.y1 = node1.y
- link.x2 = node2.x
- link.y2 = node2.y

Ideally, whenever the position of a node changes, the position of all its in and out `Link`s should change as well. I would like to access it like so: `linkInstance.x1 = nodeInstance1.x`.

Here's what I've tried:

```cs
class Link : ReactiveBase
{
    private int x1;
    private int y1;
    private int x2;
    private int y2;

    private Node fromNode;
    private Node toNode;

    //Just copies value, no updates.
    public int X1 { get {return this.fromNode.X;} }
    public int Y1 { get {return this.fromNode.Y;} }
    public int X2 { get {return this.toNode.X;} }
    public int Y2 { get {return this.toNode.Y;} }

    //Binding to From.X in xaml works; but don't like accessing node from  link
    public Node From { get { return this.fromNode; } }
    //...

    public Link(Node from, Node to)
    {
        this.fromNode = from;
        this.toNode = to;

        //works; but quite a lot of work
        from.PropertyChanged += test;
        //...
    }

    private void test(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "X")
        {
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("X1");
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == "Y")
        {
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Y1");
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Is there are a simpler way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a simpler solution:

```
class Node: ViewModelBase
{    
    private int _X;
    public int X
    {
        get => _X;
        set
        {
            _X = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(X)));
        }
    }

    private int _Y;
    public int Y
    {
        get => _Y;
        set
        {
            _Y = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Y)));
        }
    }
}

class Link: ViewModelBase
{
    public Link(Node from, Node to)
    {
        FromNode = from;
        ToNode = to;
    }
    
    private Node _FromNode;
    public Node FromNode
    {
        get => _FromNode;
        set
        {
            _FromNode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FromNode)));
        }
    }
    private Node _ToNode;
    public Node ToNode
    {
        get => _ToNode;
        set
        {
            _ToNode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ToNode)));
        }
    }
}
```

Where `ViewModelBase` is a base class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Instead of having your `Link` hold the coordinates of a set of nodes, it can hold a reference to the nodes themselves, that way you don't need to handle the `X` and `Y` property updates since they are handled by the `Node` itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple. A `Node` has a collection of `Link` items. A `Link` connects two `Node` objects hence has two endpoints: a source node and a destination node. You always add a `Link` to the link collection of the source `Node`. Going by this rule, `Link` only needs to store the reference to the destination `Node` in a property `Destination` (and maybe additional data like a description etc.).

When drawing the links, you just have to iterate over each `Node` and iterate over the link collection. Then draw a line from current `Node` to current `Link.Destination`.
You see that the point of view has changed: a `Node` has zero or more `Link` objects that point to a single neighbor. `Link` is the "passive" part of the relationship. Instead of looking at the graph from the view of a `Link` you change to look at it from the `Node` perspective and move from `Node` to `Node`. `Link` no longer cares about `Node`, but `Node` cares about `Link` i.e `Node` has a `Link`.

This results in a directed graph, that can be traversed by accessing the `Link` items of the `Node.Links` collection. For an undirected graph you would have to maintain a reference to both `Node´ endpoints in the` Link` object.

`Link` data itself doesn't have an explicit position. This allows the connection point drawing to float around the node's boundaries when the `Node` is dragged e.g. across a `Canvas`. The `Link` implicitly is positioned by the owner (the source's `Node.Position`)
and the endpoint (`Link.Destination.Position`).

In other words, you have to distinguish between the data models and their rendered view elements. A `Node` has a position. A `Link` doesn't, but connects two `Node` objects i.e. connects two positions. On view/render level the element that maps to a `Link` e.g. a `Line` has a different position than the `Node` element e.g. a `Rectangle`.

You need an engine that draws the elements by traversing the graph:

1. Take a `Node` (source of the `Link`) and create a `Rectangle`.
2. Bind the position of the `Rectangle` to the `Node.Position` of the current `Node`.
3. Iterate over its `Link` items of the `Node.Links` collection:
   for each `Link` create a `Line` and bind its start point to the current `Node.Position` and its endpoint to the current link's `Link.Destination.Position` (identify the edge of the `Rectangle` that is closest to the destination `Node` i.e. apply layout algorithm e.g. by using a `IValueConverter`).

Because of the data binding on view level, the drawing that represents a `Link` will follow the position of the node drawing. On data level the `Link` has no position.

**Link .cs**

```
// Minimal version that create a directed graph, 
// since only the destination node is referenced
class Link : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private Node destination;
  public Node Destination
  {
    get => this.destination;
    set
    {
      this.destination = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  // Some additional data associated with this Link
  private string description;   
  public string Description
  {
    get => this.description;
    set 
    { 
      this.description = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

**Node Node.cs**

```
class Node : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<Link> Links { get; set; }

  private Point position;   
  public Point Position
  {
    get => this.position;
    set 
    { 
      this.position = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

**Example**

```
var sourceNode = new Node();
var destinationNode = new Node();

// Connect both nodes from source to destination
var link = new Link() { Destination = destinationNode };
sourceNode.Links.Add(link);
```

**Remarks**

If the link itself is not intended to carry data aside from the destination node (and optional source node), you can drop it and add the destination nodes directly to a collection of the source node instead e.g. `Node.Neighbors`.
Then the link becomes a pure view element. On data level the link would be indicated by the fact that the `Node` holds references to neighboring `Node` objects.